# Embed Album Art in Mp3 using Tag Lib C#

Tags: c#, ios6, taglib, id3-tag, taglib-sharp

Trying to add Album art using c# tag lib,

```
  TagLib.File trackFile = TagLib.File.Create(strLocalFile);
  Picture picture = new Picture("Picture path");
  picture.Type = PictureType.FrontCover;
  picture.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
  picture.Description = "Front Cover";        
  trackFile.Tag.Pictures = new IPicture[1] { picture };
  trackFile.Save();
```

I get picture in windows media player, itunes and iphone (only in portrait mode). When i switch to landscape mode, album art is displayed but when slide across the cover flow album art disappears.

Am i missing something in code ?

I use iTunes 11, iOS 6 on iPhone 4s

Comment: **Update :** This specific issue was due to iPhone's selective resolution. When i decreased the image's **resolution**, album arts displayed correctly in iPhone's cover flow mode.

Answer (score 5):

Let me cite myself:

I found that iTunes hates UTF-16 and that's what's the problem there.

```
targetMp3File = TagLib.File.Create(...);

// define picture
TagLib.Id3v2.AttachedPictureFrame pic = new TagLib.Id3v2.AttachedPictureFrame();
pic.TextEncoding = TagLib.StringType.Latin1;
pic.MimeType     = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
pic.Type         = TagLib.PictureType.FrontCover;
pic.Data         = TagLib.ByteVector.FromPath(...);

// save picture to file
targetMp3File.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[1] { pic };    
targetMp3File.Save();
```

So essentially the whole thing is in the `pic.TextEncoding` line. Additionally i assigned the Mime Type through the .NET constant.

**Source:** [Having trouble writing ArtWork with Taglib-sharp 2.0.4.0 in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237346/having-trouble-writing-artwork-with-taglib-sharp-2-0-4-0-in-net/13688851#13688851)

This should work for both iTunes and iPod/iPad/iPhone. BUT this works only for MP3 files...